# How to best describe a bunch of 2D histograms/distributions?

Tags: distributions, histogram, heatmap

For chords of several music genres, I have subjective ratings from subjects that show how pleasant they found each chord (x axis below) and also how consonant (y axis). A scatter plot (or rather a heat map) of the two dimensions is plotted below for four of these genres. 
[image]

I am wondering what is the best quantitative metric of describing the "mode" of each distribution, if I want to be able to say something about how pleasantness and consonance are related to each other for the various musical genres. For instance, for Jazz, it is clear that most data points are located within (i.e. the "whitest" square is at) position x=5,y=3, corresponding to there being lots of rather pleasant but not very consonant chords in that genre. But the distribution of "white-enough" squares varies across the musical genres.

What is the best summary of this data set? I reckon a curve of best fit would not necessarily be the best metric, as it does not capture where exactly along the curve it is that most points are clustered.

Comment: These displays seem to be useful summaries of your results. They are even "quantitative," showing the relative distributions of rankings in these 2 dimensions. Why do you need something more?

Comment: As I said the first thought after producing these histograms was to try and fit a curve to them, but realised that they would not be informative in this case. So you would just leave it at that then?

Comment: I don't know the expectations of your intended audience, but to me it seems that any multi-modal 2-dimensional curve fitting (as might be needed for classical and jazz) would be quite arbitrary and might obfuscate more than clarify. I'd leave it. Just my opinion.

Comment: Would permutation statistics tell me anything informative? For instance, compute the centre of mass of each distribution, then randomly shuffle the data and recompute the DV .. do that 10,000 times to obtain the distribution, then compute the p-value for the original DV on the basis of that distribution.

Comment: That would seem to make sense if you need to calculate some measure of "statistical significance" for the data summary as displayed. There also are ways to do more traditional significance testing for comparing 2D distributions. That's a bit beyond the scope of the present question or its title, and it's outside my expertise. You might get a more informed response if you pose a new question (or rewrite this one and its title) with that issue at the forefront.